# Array of $_POST PHP

Tags: arrays, post, foreach

I have a form which where I receive some $_POST data. In a submitAction.php (for example) I did 2 steps, first I assign to a variable what I receive in $_POST for each input field, and second I push the variable to an array of fields; this:
first:

```
$pais= $_POST['pais'];
$horario = $_POST['horario'];
```

second:

```
$fields = array(
'pais' => "eeuu",
'horario' => "pdt",
);
```

I have simplify the number of fields but In reality I have more. I have an array with the names of the $fields array keys, that came from another part of the application.
The problem is that I am trying to automatize this process, because if not I have to edit this submitAction.php for each form that I have in my application.
I am trying to code a for each statement to iterate and did the assign of the $_POST['whatever'] to the $fields key that match, but I am not sure how to do it.
Any help? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some difficulty understanding your question, but I presume that you wanted to take the field names and their corresponding values from the POST request (but only from the fields which you have stated in an array) and assign them to a multidimensional array. The code below should help you.

```
$keyNames = array("pais", "horario");
$fields = array();

foreach($keyNames as $keyName){
  $fields[$keyName] = $_POST[$keyName];
}
```